# Generate multidimensional array from two other multidimensional array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hopefully someone can help me :)

I have two arrays of distributor Products Info from separate datasources but with same structure. They are held in code as variables $distro1Products and $distro2Products.

Distro1:

```
    [MZ-V7S500BW] => Array
        (
            [wooCode] => 13220
            [price] => 74.00
            [quantity] => 25
        )
     [...] => Array (.......)
     MZ-V7S500BW - distro product code
```

Distro2:

```
    [1256421] => Array
        (
            [wooCode] => 13220
            [price] => 82.84
            [quantity] => 50
        )
    [...] => Array (.......)
    1256421- distro product code
```

What I want to do is to generate new array from both array results, something like this

```
    [13220] => Array
        (
            [price] => 74.00
            [quantity] => 25
        )
```

I don't know if I can ask help with logic - script should pick cheapier entry (in this case - from Distro1) but it also must check if product is in stock (quantity > 0) and if both entries are out of stock, just return 0.
What I really really need right now is a way to generate new multidimensional array from existing two multidimensional arrays, also I have plans of integrating third distro, so expandability of code would be super nice :)

Thanks in advance! ♥

Comment: This question is Unclear because the [mcve] does not accurately express the logical rules.  Please do not "yatta-yatta" the input data or the exact desired output.  We need to have a clear expression of the requirement and a sufficiently challenging example to be able to differentiate between correct answers and incorrect answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is this working :

```php
$distro1Products = [
    'MZ-V7S500BW' => [
        'wooCode' => 13220,
        'price' => 74.00,
        'quantity' => 25
    ]
];
        
$distro2Products = [
    13220 => [
        'price' => 74.00,
        'quantity' => 25
    ]
];

$fusion = array_merge(...array_map(function($code, $tab) use($distro2Products) {
    $wooCode = $tab['wooCode'];
    return [$wooCode => $distro2Products[$wooCode]];
}, array_keys($distro1Products), $distro1Products));
```

?
The goal is to find how to have a link between 'wooCode' value from first array and key from second array. When you got association, you can build your array.